# How can I add custom UseSpa that uses razor index.cshtml insted of static files in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, angular2-routing

**How should it work?**

Through an *ASP.NET CORE 2.2 Angular 2* web application I need detailed information from a angular control list, so my team we have found the best option to display this detailed list in a different browser window once the user clicks the row.

**What is the problem?**

The problem is that I have a huge client *JSON* that contains the current list state. And to be able to view the detailed list I need to generate a *SQL* on the server with this JSON state. Finally with the *SQL* response, the server *API* should response with detailed list to client in another window, so this *JSON* state request cannot be sended to *query string HTML URI*(it's too big), but it is necessary that they be passed serialized by *POST*.

**First ideas.**

1. It Would be, to have an end point action and build dynamic
   index2.html. I think it is the most appropriate option, but I don't
   know how I could modify index2.html from the server, I no longer
   have access to it because I use the `UseSpa middleware`. Basically I would 
   need a custom UseSpa that uses cshtml instead of static index.html.

   ```
       app.UseSpa(spa =>
       {
           spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
           if (env.IsDevelopment())
           {
               spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
           }
       });
   ```
2. Share data *cookie* between browser windows. But is smells bad, xss attacks, race conditions...
3. Use `window.postMessage()`. But doesn't work in all
   browsers.

So summarizing, how could I open a new window with an *asp net core angular* application, with a *POST* request, and return a new *html index*(.*cshtml*) or some kind of alternative in order to have a angular detailed row control in a new window with the data result of the `action` generated through the *post* request?

**Some information.**

We 've created an *Angular* project template in *VS 2017.*

Comment: Can't you fetch the data in Angular with HTTP get? Generate the JSON in your backend and then fetch and display it in Angular?

Comment: @Enrico, it's mandatory to open it in another browser window, and that the data sent is through POST. I cannot fetch the data using GET because I need to send the JSON state that cannot be displayed in the URL and the data is too big.

Comment: I'd use the angular httpclient rather than passing your data through URLS ...

Comment: @Enrico. Yes I use angular HttpClient, but how can I open a new tab window with POST sent data.